# ¿Cómo poner un div al lado del otro sin que se vayan para abajo y sin usar flex?

Tags: html, css

Tengo que hacer lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y que al achicar la pantalla se queden igual al lado del otro, hay que usar `position` y no se puede utilizar flex ni grid. Sin esas propiedades no consigo que se queden una al lado del otro.

He supuesto que hay que hacer un `div` que contenga otro `div` con el texto y un tercero con la imagen, llevo esto pero no sé qué hacer para que se posicionen uno al lado del otro

```css
.texto1 {
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 3em 1em;
}

.caja1 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.imagen1 {
}

img {
  width: 22rem;
  height: 14rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="caja1">
  <div class="texto1">Clear Beach</div>
  <div class="imagen1"> <img src="//placehold.it/220x140/" /> </div>
</div>

<div class="caja1">
  <div class="texto1">Clear Beach</div>
  <div class="imagen1"> <img src="//placehold.it/220x140/" /> </div>
</div>

<div class="caja1">
  <div class="texto1">Clear Beach</div>
  <div class="imagen1"> <img src="//placehold.it/220x140/" /> </div>
</div>

<div class="caja1">
  <div class="texto1">Clear Beach</div>
  <div class="imagen1"> <img src="//placehold.it/220x140/" /> </div>
</div>

<div class="caja1">
  <div class="texto1">Clear Beach</div>
  <div class="imagen1"> <img src="//placehold.it/220x140/" /> </div>
</div>
```

No se ven las imagenes pero salen justo debajo, así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Podrías hacerlo de dos formas:

1. Aplica a los elemento div, `display: inline`. Esto sobreescribe el comportamiento estandar de un , `display: block`
2. Usa  en lugar de , que por defecto usa `display: inline`

Answer (score -1):

Prueba a ponerle a las imagenes `float:left`:

EDIT: La clase seria caja1 no imagen1

```
.caja1 {
    float:left;
}
```

Lo que hace es básicamente lo mismo que flex.

Si no ajustas el tamaño de la imagen correctamente ésta saltará abajo.

Comment: Aunque float es una opción para este caso, la frase: "_Lo que hace es básicamente lo mismo que flex_" necesita alguna aclaración porque hay un trecho muy grande de lo que hace Flexbox a lo que hace float. También, deberías añadir algo más de información en la respuesta: ¿dónde iría el `float: left;` en el código compartido? ¿haría falta algo más de código? ¿cómo o por qué funciona esta solución y qué problemas podría plantear?

Comment: Yo le digo la solucion, tampoco le voy a dar todo masticado, de ahi que cada uno investigue

Comment: El problema es que `.imagen1 {
    float:left;
}` por si solo no resuelve el problema. De hecho, se sigue viendo igual que antes. No digo que se lo des todo masticado, pero es que la solución propuesta no funciona tal y como está.

Comment: También debo decir que si lo pregunto por aquí es porque ya he investigado y no he encontrado nada que me despejara la duda y agregando el float left no me ha servido, estoy de acuerdo con Álvaro, aún así gracias por la respuesta

Comment: A ver no he probado tu codigo, pero la instruccion que te he dado funciona para lo que pides, si tan mal me explico te invito a que busques sobre float en w3schools y ahi enxontraras la solucion